# read xml file from end to start in php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

i want to read xml file from end to start suppose my xml like that :

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
<note>
<to>Samy</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't Miss me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

i need to read last note first i use code like that

```
$x = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('note');
        $nofnews = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('note')->length;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $nofnews; $i++) {
            $item_title = $x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('to')
                            ->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $item_link = $x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('from')
                            ->item(0)->nodeValue;
                            }
```

thank you in advance

Comment: You only need to read the last note node first, or first the last note node and then back to the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a [`DOMNodeList`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php). You can access each element by it's numerical index (0 to length-1) as you already do, but just start at the end, not the beginning in your for loop, then count downwards:

```
$x = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('note');
$nofnews = $x->length;
for ($i = $nofnews-1; $i > -1; $i--)
{
    $item = $x->item($i);
    $item_title = $item->getElementsByTagName('to')
                        ->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $item_link = $item->getElementsByTagName('from')
                        ->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

This should already to it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand your question correctly but it seems you want to start reading
 the XML document's root element's children in reverse order?

(Also the example content you're giving is taken from here: http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_xml_simplexml.asp) why not follow their example?

But anyway, this should do the trick:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");

echo $xml->getName() . "<br />";

foreach(array_reverse($xml->children()) as $child)
  {
  // process your child element in here
  }
?>
```

--> make use of the array_reverse() function: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_reverse.asp